# Jump to Anchor from CodeBehind without repost

Tags: asp.net, html, postback, anchor, code-behind

Is there a way to append an anchor (test.aspx#23432) in the codebehind to the end of my current location in my address bar without using Response.Redirect()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are in your code behind, you are already in a repost, so the short answer is no.  You can change your button/link to a regular html control that appends the anchor without doing a postback

```
<a href="#23432">Click Here</a>
```